# How to change the HSV values of an image in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I am able to convert an image from the RGB to HSV colorspace, but how can I then manipulate those values using the HSV scale as outlined in the [PIL documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageColor.html)?

```
img = Image.open("assets/image.png")
img = img.convert('HSV')
img.show()
```

Comment: Hi Michael, do you want to change the individual values of the pixels to some arbitrary value that you choose?  If so what you want is Image.putpixel where you pass the coordinate of the pixel and the value you would like to use https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html

Comment: Hi @BenJ, I might be confusing HSV and HSL, but I would like to treat the image as if it were in PhotoShop and manipulate it based upon the HSV/HSL values.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear of what exactly you are trying to achieve, but if you need to change pixel values putpixel is the way to go.  This documentation https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html is very useful and may contain what you are after

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the image to a NumPy array and manipulate it from there.

For example, to shift the hue:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import image

def hue_shift(img, amount):
    hsv_img = img.convert('HSV')
    hsv = np.array(hsv_img)
    hsv[..., 0] = (hsv[..., 0]+amount) % 360
    new_img = Image.fromarray(hsv, 'HSV')
    return new_img.convert('RGB')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you get HSV images, you can use opencv library.

import argparse.
import cv2
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "-image", required = True, help = "Path to the image");
args = vars(ap.parse_args());
image = cv2.imread(args["image"]);
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
```

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why and how you code would solve the OP's problem